# How to make the enrollment key not visible again after the student logged out once inputted?

Tags: php, mysql

Basically, i want to create an enrollment key for every subject before the student can enroll in a certain subject. For example, I am student who logs in in my account and then i want to make myself enroll in a certain subject with an enrollment key and then logged out after that. It should be, once I logged in again, i wont input the enrollment key again into that subject again because i just did it yet my code always asking for the enrolment key of that subject everytime i click that subject. please help me. this is the code:

```
    <?php
    include_once('connect.php');
session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['crs_key'])) {
$qry = "SELECT * FROM COURSE";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
$found = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        if (($_POST['crs_key'] == $row["course_enrollment_key"])) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                window.location.href='afterkey.php';
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location.href= 'afterkey.php';
                },3000);
                </script>";
            $found = 1;
            $_SESSION['key'] = $row['course_enrollment_key'];
        }

        break;
}

if($found=1) {
    if(isset($_SESSION['key'])) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                window.location.href='afterkey.php';
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location.href= 'afterkey.php';
                },3000);
                </script>";
    }


}



else if($found=0) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Invalid Enrollment key!');
                window.location.href='key.php';
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location.href= 'key.php';
                },3000);
                </script>";
        }
    }

    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Enrollment Key </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

     if (isset($_SESSION["fname"])) {
echo "<h2>Welcome ".$_SESSION['fname']."</h2>";
echo "<br /><p align='right'><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></p>";

if (isset($_SESSION['key'])) {
    echo "header(location:'afterkey.php')";
}
else {
    echo "<form name='enrollmentKey' method='post' action='key.php'>
        <div>
            <input type='text' name='crs_key' id='crs_key' placeholder='Enrollment Key' value=''>
            <br>
            <input type='submit' name='enroll' id='enroll' value='Enroll'>
        </div>
        </form>";
}
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to properly include the code that you're using, as it appears it didn't work the first time.

Comment: done. please help @Ohgodwhy i hope you understand my point. i am having a hard time here thinking what to do </3

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `found = 1` within a conditional check of your `$_POST['crs_key']` input type. This means that if that value is not passed along, then the script is going to fail and move to `else if($found=0)`.

As I can't see how your database is structured, you first need to query to see if the ID (for instance) of the user exists in a `registration_table` that matches the `course id` in question.

This is the best I can come up with.